# Possibility to change the view in Clearquest

Tags: clearquest

we have Clearquest installed in our project. I have a Clearquest query. When I execute it, it lists all the records per the query. I realise I can only see either 25, 50, 75 and 100 records per view.

Will it possible to increase the number of records per view??

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible :(

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I disagree. Not all answers must be super elaborated. If the answer is "you can't do that," why leave it as a comment?

Comment: The review process is still in beta. Without the question's context if all I see is this answer then I have to think that it could be more complete. I agree with you, but this canned comment was based on a split second decision in review mode. Sorry if it offended you.

Comment: Not at all :)
It's actually nice to see how people really care about the quality of this site's content.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which version of ClearQuest you are using.

It is true that you can't increase the page size beyond 100 in normal query view, but as of CQ 8.0.1 you can do a 'multirecord update'. This opens up a new UI on the query which allows you to view as many records as you want on one page.

To increase this beyond 100 rows, you have to be an administrator.

Go to site administration->configuration->application options.

Increase the size of the desired MRU page size here:
Maximum Multi-Record Update Page Size

Then users will be able to increase their MRU page size preference here:
Preferences->Multi-Record Update->Page size for Multi-Record Update:

Now, once you've logged off and back in again, run any query, right click and choose Multi Record Update. A new MRU tab will open up with the query in it. You'll see the page size is as you desired.

More information about multirecord update is here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH5A_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.user_web.doc/topics/t_perform_mru.htm